# Unify objects in an array, obtain totals

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm struggling through this issue.

I'm developing a picking app with a barcode scanner. I have a multi-step form which shows one product at a time. The user can pick the item and go to the next one or skip it because there is no stock of it.
I now have this array of objects, obtained after the form is submitted. It shows the code input by the user and validates it with the id of the product (i created the ids). If code: "" is empty, it's because the user skip it.

```
[
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 3929,
    "name": "Eucaliptus 90 Gr",
    "quantity": 3,
    "code": "3929"
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 3929,
    "name": "Eucaliptus 90 Gr",
    "quantity": 3,
    "code": "3929"
  },
 {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 3929,
    "name": "Eucaliptus 90 Gr",
    "quantity": 3,
    "code": ""
  },
 {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 2739,
    "name": "Hellmanns 232 Ml",
    "quantity": 4,
    "code": "2739"
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 2739,
    "name": "Hellmanns 232 Ml",
    "quantity": 4,
    "code": "2739"
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 2739,
    "name": "Hellmanns 232 Ml",
    "quantity": 4,
    "code": ""
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 2739,
    "name": "Hellmanns 232 Ml",
    "quantity": 4,
    "code": ""
  }
]
```

And i'm looking to obtain the totals, how many items of the same product where picked and which didn't.

This is an example of what i need:

```
[
 {
   "orderid": "12696",
   "id": 3929,
   "name": "Eucaliptus 90 Gr",
   "quantity": 3,
   "picked": 2,
   "notPicked": 1
 },
 {
   "orderid": "12696",
   "id": 2739,
   "name": "Hellmanns 232 Ml",
   "quantity": 4,
   "picked": 2,
   "notPicked": 2
 }
]
```

Thanks in advance !

This is my code:

```
// Here i grab all the code inputs, even empty ones
const totalItemsPickedArr = req.body.code;

//I convert that array of codes into an array of objects    
let newTotalItemsArr = totalItemsPickedArr.map(code => {
        return ({
            code
        })
    })


// I bring all the items from the order via sequelize
db.Detallepedido.findAll({
            where: {
                pedido_id: orderid
            },
            include: [{ all: true, nested: true }],
            order: [['productoorden', 'orden', 'ASC']]
})
.then(products => {
// Here i map the promise and make a new array of objects with the data i need.

let productListArr = products.map(product => {
                    return ({
                        orderid: orderid,
                        id: product.producto_id,
                        name: product.producto_nombre,
                        price: product.precio,
                        quantity: product.cantidad,
                        order: product.productoorden.orden,
                        category:
product.productoorden.categoriaproducto[0].categoria_id,
                        
                    })
                })
// Flattened makes each object multiply by its quantity, so it returns a bigger array, like the one i showed in the first array.
const flattened = productListArr.reduce((acc, item) => {
                    return [
                        ...acc,
                        ...Array.from({ length: item.quantity }, () => ({...item}))
                        
                    ]
                }, [])

//then i make a new array with the flattened array and I paste the code the user input.
let newProductListArr = flattened.map((product, index) => {
                    return ({
                        ...product, 
                        ...newTotalItemsArr[index]})
                })
```

After i flattened the array, i need to just show one object for each product and add the totals picked/notPicked based on the code inputted.

Sorry if it's too complicated, i know it's not the best code. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @limido i've tried reduce, but i cant figure out how to obtain the totals based on if the attribute "code" is empty or not.

Comment: Please add you code to the question so we can guide you

Comment: @limido i edited and added the code

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this approach based on the array you posted and the expected array results.

I didn't went into the details of your whole code, but just wanted to point out how to perform the conversion.

```js
let scans = [{...}] // all of the items

let groups = scans.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let { id, code } = cur
  let { picked, notPicked } = acc[id] || { picked: 0, notPicked: 0 }

  // perform operations to count modifying the variables
  if (code === '')
    notPicked++
  else
    picked++

  acc[id] = { ...cur, picked, notPicked }
  return acc
}, {})

let converted = Object.values(groups)
```

Comment: In english, i'm not getting how the operations to get the totals work. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Updated the answer to add some logic for the counter variables